# Move data from Azure Data Lake to Big Query

Tags: azure, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I wanted to move some data on daily basis from azure data lake to Big query using Azure Data Factory. However, ADF does not support Big Query as sink. What would you suggest? Any GCP service analogue to ADF to perform this task?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> However, ADF does not support Big Query as sink.

Yes, ADF can only support Google Big Query as the source. So this means ADF can not achieve your requirement.

> Any GCP service analogue to ADF to perform this task?

It seems that there is no ready-made tool, maybe you can write code to get data from datalake and copy it?

Comment: Yes. That might be an option. Do you have any experience with cloud composer?